# Gatsby Dynamic Rebuild Static Pages on Production

Tags: reactjs, api, npm, refresh, gatsby

I write my first Gatsby Page. I also use Laravel as backend server.
In my project i have many slug pages. I used createPages and api connection to create them. User can add files like images, audio files and pdf. When it happen, page should change a bit content and show this file on specify address. Develop version works fine (i bind button to start npm run refresh). I used gatsby refresh endpoint and add to scripts:

```
"refresh": "curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/__refresh"
```

And it's work fine. But i don't know how change this to use it properly on production build. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT` environment variable is only working on development. According to the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/refreshing-content/):

> During local development, it can be useful to refresh sourced content
> without restarting the development server. To facilitate this, Gatsby
> exposes an environment variable called `ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT`.

What you need is called a [webhook](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/cloud/docs/webhook/). Basically, a webhook is a way for an application to trigger a change that happens in real-time in a CMS.

Each CMS has its own way of implementing webhooks, but the idea is to trigger a build process once a change in your CMS occurs.